# controlling scrollbar height with css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm writing a website and currently experiencing a problem where the vertical scrollbar scrolls a lot more than the content of the webpage.  For example, if I have 300px worth of content (in height), the scrollbar might scroll all the way down to 600px.  So by the time I scroll down to the bottom, I have 300 px of blank white.  How can I adjust either the page height or the scrollbar so that it only allows a user to scroll as far as the end of the page content?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: "controlling scrollbar height" and "adjusting content height" is two different things. It sounds like you want to do the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the content a height. Text will automatically create the height of the content.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mSVnx/1/